# Operator<< cant access private int of class

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

I get this when i try to compile:

> ../Monster.h:26:9: error: ‘int ProjectIV::Monster::con’ is private
>
> ```
> `int con;`
>      ^
> ```
>
> ../Monster.cpp:17:39: error: within this context
>
> `cout << "Constitution: " << monster.con << endl;`
>                                          ^
>
> make: *** [Monster.o] Error 1

From what I understand making operator<< a friend should allow it to access int con. What am I not seeing.

Monster.h:

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H_
#define MONSTER_H_

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
#include <string>
using std::string;

namespace ProjectIV
{
  class Monster
  {
  friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const Monster &monster);
  public:
    Monster(int con);
  private:
    int con;
  };
} /* namespace ProjectIV */

#endif /* MONSTER_H_ */
```

Monster.cpp:

```
#include "Monster.h"

ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const ProjectIV::Monster &monster)
{
  cout << "Constitution: " << monster.con << endl;

  return out;
}

ProjectIV::Monster::Monster(int con): con(con)
{}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Monster.h"
using namespace ProjectIV;

int main()
{
  Monster Gojira(140);
  cout << Gojira << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use "using" at global scope in header files: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2717709/4323  This probably won't fix your problem, but it's good advice for C++.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ProjectIV::Monster& monster)
```

should be:

```
ostream& ProjectIV::operator<<(ostream& out, const ProjectIV::Monster& monster)
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1afe9712fe0ff6bd) your *not working* example, and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c638fca632a5395c) is the working one.

---

Also, as per [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/andreyt)'s comment, you should add a function declaration before the `friend` declaration:

```
namespace ProjectIV {
    class Monster {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Monster& monster);
    public:
        Monster(int con);
    private:
        int con;
    };
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Monster& monster);
    // ^^^ this
}
```

Comment: This is not enough. Friend declaration *refers* to `ProjectIV::operator<<`, that is true. But it does not introduce a declaration for `ProjectIV::operator<<` into `ProjectIV` namespace. Without such declaration, it is illegal to define `ProjectIV::operator<<` in global namespace. G++ rejects the code. An explicit declaration for `operator<<` must be added to `ProjectIV` namespace. (clang++ apparently accepts the code.)

Comment: @AndreyT, true. Thanks. That's weird that Clang++ accepts it instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

Firstly, the friend declaration inside `Monster` class refers to `ProjectIV::operator <<` function. It is `ProjectIV::operator <<` that will become the friend of `Monster`. What you defined in your `Monster.cpp` file is actually a `::operator <<`. This is a completely different function that is not a friend of `Monster`. This is why you get the error.

So, you need to decide what function you want to make a friend - the one in global namespace or the one in `ProjectIV` namespace - and act accordingly.

If you want to make your `operator <<` a member of `ProjectIV` namespace, you run into the second problem. Friend declarations *refer* to member of enclosing namespace, but they don't *introduce* the corresponding declarations into the enclosing namespace. It is still your responsibility to add a declaration for `operator <<` in `ProjectIV`

```
namespace ProjectIV
{

  class Monster
  {
  friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const Monster &monster);
  public:
    Monster(int con);
  private:
    int con;
  };

  ostream &operator<< (ostream &out, const Monster &monster);

} /* namespace ProjectIV */
```

and then later define it as a member of `ProjectIV`

```
ostream &ProjectIV::operator<< (ostream &out, const ProjectIV::Monster &monster)
{
  cout << "Constitution: " << monster.con << endl;

  return out;
}
```